# hide values in tables if the length of data is less than criteria

Tags: r

I am looking to hide values from the output table if the frequency of data in the respective variable is less than 4 .

lets say if the number of records in column hp, mpg, qsec is less than 4 than the mean or median should be masked with "--"

i am trying like below but not working.

In this case if valid_n is less than 4 than mean , median should be shown as "--"

```
library(expss)
data <- data.frame(
  gender = c(1, 2, 1),
  sector = c(3, 3, 1),
  col1 = c(12, 15, 22),
  col2 = c(33, NA, 41),
  col3 = c(1, 1, 0),
  col4 = c(1, 0, 0),
  col5 = c(1, 2, 1)
)

data$col3 <- factor(data$col3, levels = 1, labels = "Management")
data$col4 <- factor(data$col4, levels = 1, labels = "HR")

lst <- list(data$col4,data$col3)
mean_mask =3
median_mask =3


fun1 <- function(dataset,var_list,banner1){
  perc_25 <- function(x, ...){unname(quantile(x, .25, na.rm=TRUE))}
  perc_75 <- function(x, ...){unname(quantile(x, .75, na.rm=TRUE))}
  mask_m<-function(x,N){
    x= ifelse(N<mean_mask,"--",x)
  }
  
  mask_me<-function(x,N){
    x= ifelse(N<median_mask,"--",x)
  }
  
  dataset<-dataset[var_list] %>% as.data.frame() 
  first_col_param <- head(var_list,1)
  second_col_param <- tail(var_list,1)
  var_lab(colnames(dataset)[ncol(dataset)]) <- ""
  mr <- parse(text=paste0("mrset(",
                          first_col_param ," %to% ",second_col_param,")"))
  t1<- cross_fun(dataset, 
                 eval(mr),
                 col_vars = banner1,
                 fun = combine_functions("Mean" = mask_m(mean,5), 
                                         "Median" = mask_me(median,5),
                                         "Max"= max,
                                         "Min"=min,
                                         "25th Perc" = perc_25,
                                         "75th Perc" = perc_75,
                                         "Valid N" = valid_n
                 ))
  
  t1
}

mask = 5
t1 <- fun1(dataset=data,"col1",banner1=lst)
```

the required output should be look like below
[image]

Comment: Is this based on Valid N?  Based on the example with mtcars showed, none of the Valid N are less than 4? Is the output based on a modified dataset

Comment: @akrun yes based on valid_n,yes  I tried with modified data. I just filtered this mtcars data to sample of 3 records

Comment: I tried by adding some NAs, but then your function creates blanks for some cells

Comment: What can be other solution…? Actually the data will be numeric values and blank values

Comment: Can you post the original data that you used as I can't reproduce the values you showed i.e. you can use `dput`

Comment: Also, in your function, `ifelse(N<median_mask,"--",x)`, it is not actually checking the valid N

Comment: I just updated the reproducible example, ifelse(N<median_mask,"--",x), actually i was given the N hard coded in function itself and also tried with replacing N with Valid_n but didn't work. please suggest what need to be changes to get the desired result.

Comment: Now Valid_n from your data is 1 and Mean, Median for HR, Management is 12 and 13.5

Comment: The variable can be col1 or col2 both are numeric.

Comment: I am not able create a logic how to do this because requirements is expss output table only.

Comment: Try the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
fun1 <- function(dataset,var_list,banner1){
  perc_25 <- function(x, ...){unname(quantile(x, .25, na.rm=TRUE))}
  perc_75 <- function(x, ...){unname(quantile(x, .75, na.rm=TRUE))}
  
  dataset<-dataset[var_list] %>% as.data.frame() 
  first_col_param <- head(var_list,1)
  second_col_param <- tail(var_list,1)
  var_lab(colnames(dataset)[ncol(dataset)]) <- ""
  mr <- parse(text=paste0("mrset(",
                          first_col_param ," %to% ",second_col_param,")"))
  fun_replace_valid_n <- function(x, n) {
        dat <- cur_data_all()
        func_name <- dat$func_name
        if(x[func_name == "Valid N"] < n) {
       replace(x, func_name %in% c("Mean", "Median"), "--") 
    
  } else x
  }
  
  
  t1<- cross_fun(dataset, 
                 eval(mr),
                 col_vars = banner1,
                 fun = combine_functions("Mean" =  mean, 
                                         "Median" = median,
                                         "Max"= max,
                                         "Min"=min,
                                         "25th Perc" = perc_25,
                                         "75th Perc" = perc_75,
                                         "Valid N" = valid_n
                 ))
  
  t1 <- as.data.frame(t1) %>%
    tidyr::separate(row_labels, into = c('grp', 'func_name'), sep = "\\|") %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(grp) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(across(where(is.numeric), fun_replace_valid_n, n = 4)) %>%
      dplyr::ungroup() %>%
      tidyr::unite(row_labels, grp, func_name, sep = "|") %>%
      as.etable
  t1
  
}
```

-testing

```
> fun1(dataset=data,"col1",banner1=lst)
                                       
 |      |           | HR | Management |
 | ---- | --------- | -- | ---------- |
 | col1 |      Mean | -- |         -- |
 |      |    Median | -- |         -- |
 |      |       Max | 12 |         15 |
 |      |       Min | 12 |         12 |
 |      | 25th Perc | 12 |      12.75 |
 |      | 75th Perc | 12 |      14.25 |
 |      |   Valid N |  1 |          2 |
```